# Flutter dart compiled fail due to EdgeInsets.all when use value in global variable

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Error:

> **Argument of a constant creation must be constant expressions.**

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
        return _MyAppState();
      }
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      List<String> _products = ['Food Tester'];
      var _font_size = 20.0;

      build(context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('EasyList'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin:  EdgeInsets.all(_font_size),
                child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Add product'),
              ),
              ),
            Column(children: _products.map((element) =>Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[Image.asset("assets/food.jpg"), Text(element)],
                ),
              )).toList()),

            ],
          ),
        ));
      }
    }
```

Note: when argument as static I mean `20.0` then it is working perfect but if we take it as variable that time Dart compilation is failed. Here variable is passing inside `EdgeInsets.all` method and compilation is failed.

Comment: Please add the full and exact error output to your question.

Comment: Error is resolved @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double _font_size = 20;

    .....

}
```

This is use constants only so we need to declare const as a variable.

Comment: The code in your question does not contain any `const`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that seems to be the answer that Vishal Patoliya ツ wants to convey: `const` was missing, error message said `const` was required, solution is to add `const`.

Comment: @Cœur I guess you are right. It's probably `margin:  EdgeInsets.all(_font_size),` that is implicit `const`. Using `margin:  new EdgeInsets.all(_font_size),` would probably have solved it as well but making the font size const is better anyway if possible. I expected a `const` keyword somewhere to create a `const` context. Some Dart 1 knowledge interfered I guess.